# Recursive Function in Minesweeper

Tags: c

I'm currently working on coding the game of minesweeper for a school project, but I'm stuck on the part where we reveal the mine that the user wants and if it's a 0, reveal all the mines around it, and so on. I made my game board 2 rows and columns larger than what the actual user-specified game board size should be so that I have a border around it to count the number of mines around edge cases. (num_rows and num_cols are the dimensions that the board actually should be)

```
x x x x x x x   Quick illustration of what my board looks like.
x . . . . . x   '.' in this picture represent tiles of the actual game 
x . . . . . x   board while 'x' is the border around it
x . . . . . x
x . . . . . x
x x x x x x x
```

The code that I posted below always results in segmentation error. I think that it's a problem with when I run into the border. Anyone have any suggestions? Sorry if the code is really bad/hard to read. I'm a beginner to C and programming in general. Thanks in advance!

```
typedef struct Tile_struct {  //board struct definitions
       int visibility;
       int num_mines_around;
    } Tile;


typedef struct Board_struct {
   int num_rows;
   int num_cols;
   int num_mines;
   Tile** the_board;
} Board;

//This is how I allocated memory for the board
void CreateBoard(char** argv, Board* board) {

   int row, col;

   board->num_rows = atoi(argv[1]);
   board->num_cols = atoi(argv[2]);
   board->num_mines = atoi(argv[3]);

   board->the_board = (Tile**)malloc(board->num_rows * sizeof(Tile*));

   for (row = 0; row < (board->num_rows) + 2; row++) {

      board->the_board[row] = (Tile*)malloc(board->num_cols * 
      sizeof(Tile));

      for (col = 0; col < (board->num_cols) + 2; col++) {

          board->the_board[row][col].visibility = 0;  //hide all tiles
      }
    }
 } 

void RevealTiles(Board* board, int row, int col) {    

   int i, j;

   if (row <= 0 || row >= board->num_rows + 1 || col <= 0 || col >= 
board->num_cols + 1) {
      return;
   }
   else if (board->the_board[row][col].num_mines_around != 0) { 
      board->the_board[row][col].visibility = 4;  //reveal that tile
   }
   else {
      board->the_board[row][col].visibility = 4;
      for (i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
         for (j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
            if (i == row && j == col) {
               continue;
            }
            RevealTiles(board, i, j);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Can you please show us how have you declared (and initialized) `Board`?

Comment: `if (row <= 0 || row >= board->num_rows + 1` looks like code is indexing the array starting at 1.  I'd expect `if (row < 0 || row >= board->num_rows ...` as C arrays index starts at 0.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but how have you allocated memory for `the_board`?

Comment: `if (i == row && j == col) { continue; }` is strange too

Comment: @Bob, sorry I included that too now! Thanks!

Comment: (i == row && j == col) is so I only look at the tiles around of the current one

Comment: You are not allocating enough memory for the columns: `board->the_board[row] = malloc(board->num_cols * sizeof(Tile));` should be `board->the_board[row] = malloc((board->num_cols + 2)* sizeof(Tile));`

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you so much!! That fixed it!

Comment: Not sure about the logic of your `RevealTiles` function too. I think that it should test if the tile is already visible and in that case return without further search.

Comment: I don't understand your game plan.  Is your program playing the game and doing the guessing?  As it stands, making the functions to show the mine positions is going to be very difficult.  And in this game, there is the possibility of some uncertainty about the location of some mines only from the count of mines around.  Your tile struct should contain a mine bit, and a function should count the mines around it, you could cache that, but that's not absolutely necessary.  But you definitely need a mine bit per tile.  Hint: the entire tile struct can most definitely fit in only one byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you've been chasing this issue for a while and added a margin around the board, but this still doesn't work.  Maybe this hint will help you sort this out.  I don't think adding margins is a good idea, you should definitely try to do without but, hey, it's your app.

including the margins, your board is a 2d array, indices [0..cols+2)[0..rows+2)

So, you initial row allocation in CreateBoard() is wrong, your rows are too short by 2 units.

```
(Tile*)malloc(board->num_cols * sizeof(Tile));
```

Comment: Similar comments apply to the number of rows allocated, too.  And then there's the interesting issue of indexing the negative row number — what's the value stored in the structure again?

Comment: It should be 2bits, with a visibility flag and a mine flag, but that is a totally different story.  I don't think the purpose of this site is to do others' homework, though.